# javascript get value within an object

Tags: javascript

I got a quiz about function writing like this:

```js
/* ====== can not modify this line below till next dividing line ========= */
function foo() {
    var obj = {
        x : 1,
        y : 2,
        bar : bar()
    }

    function bar() {
/* ====== can not modify this line above ================================= */

        /* so how can I get obj.x and obj.y here and returns their sum ..? */

/* ====== can not modify this line below till next dividing line ========= */
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log( foo().bar ); // expected 3 
/* ====== can not modify this line above ================================= */
```

I found two ways myself, one is get `foo.toString()` and do some `REGEX` magic.

the other is register a global variable like `window.run` to control `foo()` runs only once.

However I am wondering is there any other ways can solve this?

Thank you for your reply~

Comment: So you want the third property as a function who call the others property ?

Comment: when you write `bar.x` and `bar.y`, I assume you mean `package.x` and `package.y` ? Also, since you expect 3, I guess you want `bar()` to return their sum?

Comment: @Aaron Sorry about my typo, it should be package.x and package.y. I have fixed it~ thank you~

Comment: @Alexis Yup, that is what I mean~

Comment: According to your comment on Alexis' answer (and also to the console.log line), you don't want the third property to be a function, but rather the result of its execution

Comment: `package` is a reserved word in "strict mode". You should assign another name

Comment: @Aaron @Alexis My fault, what I mean is how can I get `obj` properties within `bar()` function, without change the code outside `bar()`... Sorry about my poor english...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest O.K. I changed `package` into `obj`, will it seems nicer now?

Comment: No problem, I think it's quite clear now, and that Alexis had understood once you commented on his question. Still, it's better to comment about it in case people trying to help you have misunderstood. I don't know how to solve your problem myself, so I'll only be able to wish you good luck !

Comment: If the code is never modified, `return 3` solves your problem :-)

Comment: @Aaron That's fine~ thank you all the same~ :-)

Comment: @Bergi is there any way besides `return 3` or overwrite `console.log()`? of course `return 1+2` or `return Math.floor( 3.1415926535 )` is not included~ However it is still a good joke ~ :-)

Comment: Due to the order of execution, overwriting `console.log` is not as simple a solution as i first thought, that's why i deleted the comment soon after.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the quiz where you found this?

Comment: I found this in a group-chat of _weixin_ which is an instant messenger, it dose not have a link......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. `bar` is called before the object is constructed, `obj` will be `undefined` and the already-evaluated values of the previous properties (`1` and `2`) are somewhere inaccessible in memory only. See also [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572).

Given you found this question in a quiz with pretty arbitrary restrictions, they seem to expect a trick answer. There are several ways:

- Access to source code and evaluate the object literal yourself
- Simply return a constant, given that `obj.x` and `obj.y` are constant in the given code as well
- <s>Overwrite `console.log` to do your bidding, for example</s>

  ```
  function bar() {
      var log = console.log.bind(console);
      console.log = function(p) {
          log(p.valueOf());
      };
      return {
          valueOf: function() {
              return obj.x + obj.y;
          }
      };
  }
  ```

  Doesn't work unfortunately due to `console.log` being dereferenced before `foo()` is called.
  A similar approach does work in environments where the `console.log` behaviour [can be customized](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects) without needing to overwrite anything:

  ```
  function bar() {
      return {
          inspect: function() {
              return String(obj.x + obj.y);
          }
      };
  }
  ```
- Just call `foo()` yourself to get the values, but don't recurse infinitely on `bar`:

  ```
  function bar() {
      if (foo.stop) return null;
      foo.stop = true;
      var res = foo().x + foo().y;
      foo.stop = false;
      return res;
  }
  ```

Comment: I have learned so much from this answer, I am really really appreciated ~

Answer (score 1):

If it's really "*locked up*" for modification use the following "***magic***"(for test case):

```js
function foo() {
  var obj = {
    x : 1,        
    y : 2,
    bar : bar()
  }

  function bar() {
    var magic_sum = foo.toString().match(/var obj =\s*?\{\s*?x\s*?:\s*?(\d+),\s*?y\s*?:\s*?(\d+),/)
                    .slice(1,3).map(Number);

    return magic_sum[0] + magic_sum[1];
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(foo().bar);
```

The algorithm:

`foo.toString()` - getting function text representaion

`.match(/var obj =\s*?\{\s*?x\s*?:\s*?(\d+),\s*?y\s*?:\s*?(\d+),/)` - matching `x` and `y` property values

`.slice(1,3)` - getting values from captured groupes(for `x`, `y` properties)

`.map(Number)` - casting each value to *Number* type

Comment: It is really the "REGEX magic" I have metioned in the main topic ~

Comment: @NotUser9123, do you like it?

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.callingTime = foo.callingTime || 1;
    if(foo.callingTime === 1){
      foo.callingTime++;
      foo.tempObj = foo();
      return foo.tempObj.x+foo.tempObj.y;
    }
    else if(foo.callingTime === 2){
      foo.callingTime = 1;
      return;
    }
```

Comment: remember functions are objects in Javascript

Comment: using `callingTime` is also good! My way is `global variable`, calling time and foo property are both better than mine ~